# ¿como cambiar texto de botón de las herramientas de exportación en DATA TABLES?

Tags: datatables

gracias por tu tiempo.Mi pregunta es como puedo cambiar el texto en ingles por español en los botones que sirven de herramienta para exportar ya sea copiar PDF ETC ...
he intentado con el siguiente código pero solo me cambia los de anterior y siguiente y yo necesito cambiar los valores de los botones de COPY,PDF etc.. que sirve para exportar los registros de la DATA TABLE

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
  "oTableTools": {
    "sSwfPath": "js/plugins/dataTables/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
  },
  "language": {
    "paginate": {
      "previous": "Anterior",
      "next": "Siguiente",
    },
  },
});
```

Ya busque en el modulo js donde se encuentran esos botones, pero si les cambio el nombre me envía errores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se supone que es:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').DataTable({
  "oTableTools": {
    "sSwfPath": "js/plugins/dataTables/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf"
  },
  "buttons": [
    'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
  ],
  "language": {
    "paginate": {
      "previous": "Anterior",
      "next": "Siguiente",
    },
    "buttons": {
        "copy": 'Copiar',
        "csv": 'Exportar a CSV',
        ...
    }
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplemente este viene hacer el código:

```
 buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'pdf',
                    text: 'PDF'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'excel',
                    text: 'EXCEL'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'csv',
                    text: 'CSV'
                },
                {
                    extend: 'print',
                    text: 'PRINT'
                }
            ],
```

Ojo, en el "text" puedes poner cualquier palabra que se te venga en mente.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo hago de esta forma, así cambio el nombre de cada botón y a la vez inserto todos los botones en 1, también se agrega el botón para seleccionar que columnas ver:

```
$(function() {
        var table = $('#carga_grilla').DataTable({
            "pageLength": 7,
            "language": {
                "search": "Buscar:",
                "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron datos",
                "infoEmpty": "No hay datos para mostrar",
                "info": "Mostrando del _START_ al _END_, de un total de _TOTAL_ entradas",
                "paginate": {
                    "first": "Primeros",
                    "last": "Ultimos",
                    "next": "Siguiente",
                    "previous": "Anterior"
                },
            },

            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [{
                    extend: 'collection',
                    text: 'Control',
                    orientation: 'landscape',
                    buttons: [{
                            text: 'Copiar',
                            extend: 'copy'
                        }, {
                            extend: 'pdf',
                            orientation: 'landscape',
                            pageSize: 'LEGAL'
                        },
                        'csv', 'excel', 'print'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    extend: 'colvis',
                    text: 'Visor de columnas',
                    collectionLayout: 'fixed three-column'
                }
            ],
            "autoWidth": true
        })
    })
```